# Cannot get some friend-tag-me photos by v2.0, but fine with v1.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

One of my friend's photo, can be searched by the following GRAPH API with v1.0 friends_photos & friends_status permissions.

> v1.0/me/photos?type=tagged&since=1403366399&until=1404014399

To check this in v2.0, I did told my friend to become a user of our Facebook application.  However, no matter which V2.0 permission is granted, the similar query cannot get that photo.

> v2.0/me/photos?type=tagged&since=1403366399&until=1404014399

I did some pre-condition checks for this problem, and the results are

1. v2.0/me/photos?type=tagged works fine and can get some friends photos which tagged me.
2. v2.0/me/friends work fine, and that friend is in the friend list.

Any suggestion for this problem?

p.s. Forget to mention, that photo is posted at 2014/6/23, so, should not be legacy-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Check out the changelog, in v2.0 you have to go through a review process with most permissions including user_photos. Else, the permissions will only work for users with a role in your App (Developer, Admin, Tester). I assume your friend does not have a role in your App, so user_photos will not work before getting it approved by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Our application just got the approve of user_photos, however, what my friend grant to our application is user_friends.  And used test page to let her grant user_photos to our application, that photo still cannot be searched by V2.0/V2.1 API.

And after invited her to be developer, and grant our application user_status permission, that photo can get searched by v2.0/v2.1.

After some tests, user should grant user_photos, and user's friend should grant user_photos ,user_status.  Then, the user can get all privacy-allowed photos fro that friend.